# View/autocomplete org-mode tags (with group tag) as a tree structure

Tags: emacs, tree, tags, org-mode

I use org-mode tags with the "group tag" [Tags Hierarchy and groups](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Hierarchy.html).
My preferences - use the `#+TAGS:` syntax for a specific file, without overriding `org-tag-alist/org-tag-persistent-alist`. I can see list of tags in the variable `org-current-tag-alist`.
So, tags is a tree structure. The standard mini buffer org-mode for setting tags (C-c) is too inconvenient. Using autocomplete (ivy+counsel) shows tags well, but doesn't show tags hierarchy.

**Question:**

1. Is there a tool that will show tags in the form of a tree in a separate buffer? Like some modules show the directory/file structure of a project?
2. Is it possible to configure the autocomplete tools: helm/ivy+counsel/selectrum/(any other) to display a tags tree and autocomplete?

Comment: There is a specific site for [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/), this would probably be better asked there, but check their rules.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have posted  there.